# VueJs: computed properties inside an iterated property

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am not sure if the question title is the best way to accomplish what I am trying to do but first let me explain the problem:

I have a Vue root component with a property defined in the `data` key, for example `months`. In the DOM I iterate over the property using `v-for="month in months"`. Each of these `month` objects has a list of `orders` and for each `order in orders` one line is displayed in a row, with information such as `order.date` and `order.total`. This all works fine.

Now I want the bottom row to show an accumulated total for each month, but this is not available as a pre calculated property so my first guess would be to use calculated properties. But how do I define calculated properties that don't depend on the root component but on each child of an iterated property?

Another solution could possibly be using components, but I don't want to define the template inside the component but rather use what is defined in the HTML. I have not yet found a way to do this. Would this be possible? Are there any other possible solutions that I have overlooked?

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way would be to create a component for every month (and every order if it is really needed). If you want to avoid this, you can say in the month markup (assumed that orders is an array of numbers):

```
<p class="orders_total">{{month.orders.reduce((acc, el, i, arr) => acc + el )}}</p>
```

It is not a good practice because we should not define such array transformation in the markup but it should work.

Comment: Thanks, I did not even think about that I could do that but as you said, doing this calculation in line really is not as readable.  

I don't want to avoid components altogether but I want to avoid defining the template in the js file.

Answer (score 1):

I´ve solved it as you wanted in the comuted property. check it if you find something interesting.

```
<template>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
            <div v-for="(month,index) in months" :key="index">
                <p>{{ month.name }}</p>
                <ul>
                    <li v-for="(order,index) in month.orders" :key="index">
                        {{ order.title}} Total :{{ order.total}}
                    </li>
                </ul>
                Total for {{ month.name}}: {{ totalMonth[index]}}
                <hr>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
<script>
export default {
    data () {
        return {
            months:[
                {   name: 'January',
                    orders: [
                        {title: 'order1', total: 5},
                        {title: 'order2', total: 8},
                        {title: 'order3', total: 1}
                        ]
                },
                {   name: 'February',
                    orders: [
                    {title: 'order4', total: 15},
                    {title: 'order5', total: 3}
                    ]
                },
                {   name: 'March',
                    orders: [
                    {title: 'order6', total: 25}
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    computed: {
        totalMonth () {
            return this.months.map(a => a.orders.map(a => a.total).reduce((a,b) => a + b))
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Another approach I did not think about, thank you! I presume each `month` object having a calculated `total` property is not possible the way that I initially wanted?

Comment: You mean to have all the info for every month and order, and after that an ending line with the totals ?  instead of having the total on every month iteration ?

Comment: No I mean the way you did it, but with the `total` property inside each `month` object. It's not that important though, your way works

Comment: I've been researching a bit (i'm still new to vue), it could be done, but a watcher there imply a deep level of watching in the array of objects, finally i think it it over complicate things. Anyways, i think that the best aproach is using different components

Answer (score 0):

As it often happens, I found a solution shortly after formulating this question. What I am doing now is:

Defining a property in the root component as follows:

```
total: function (month) {
    // calculate total
},
```

In the DOM I display it using `{{ total(month) }} €`

This may not be an ideal solution but it works for now. If anyone has a better solution I would still appreciate the input, as I am still new to vue.js